# How to play mp4 video from URL over HTTPS on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm trying to play a video in mp4 format from URL over HTTPS using MPMoviePlayerController, but video is not playing and I receive an error in logs:

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
kind = 1;
new = 2;
old = 0;
}
```

Is any way to play this kind of video on iOS?

Here's my code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface FirstViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer;

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self playBtnPressed];
}

-(void)playBtnPressed
{
    NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://....mp4"];
    _moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_moviePlayer];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDonePressed:) name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:_moviePlayer];

    _moviePlayer.controlStyle=MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    //moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
    [_moviePlayer play];
    [self.view addSubview:_moviePlayer.view];
    [_moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDonePressed:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification object:_moviePlayer];


    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    _moviePlayer=nil;
}

- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [_moviePlayer stop];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:_moviePlayer];

    if ([_moviePlayer respondsToSelector:@selector(setFullscreen:animated:)])
    {
        [_moviePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: PLease show us your code where you setup the MPMoviePlayerController

Comment: I just edited my post by adding the code

Answer (score 0):

Probably video aspect ratio issue try setting aspect ratio

`[player setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
player.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;`

Or check if the video file is there in the specified URL location

Comment: Video file exists at URL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an iOS 7 issue.
Apparently, moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; does not work anymore.
For me, replacing it with MPMovieSourceTypeFile solved this error.
Use following code it will work for you. Be sure that you have the notification observer declared before playing movie, as follows:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)
                                                     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                   object:moviePlayerController.moviePlayer];

        moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

        [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];

        [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];

        [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: whatever i have pasted here is the solution to the problem ...Please go through it and let me know if it is working.

Comment: are u downloading the file from server and saving it to document directory? If yes, then try to save the same file in cache directory [i.e. it should be located somewhere in the iOS Caches directory (~/Library/Caches) ]instead of document directory location . And let me know if it works for u.

Comment: ALONG WITH THAT CHANGE ALSO PLEASE CHECK THE FOLLOWING TWO THINGS:   1) Make sure that you're using -fileURLWithPath: and not -URLWithString: to create your URL.                                 2)Make sure your local file has an extension (".mp4", for example). MPMoviePlayerController doesn't like files without an extension. A solution if you need to store files without an extension is to create a temporary symlink(SYMBOLIC LINK) to the actual file and give MPMoviePlayerController the file URL to that symlink instead of the "real" file.

Comment: TO CREATE SYMBOLIC LINK AND USE IN THE APP USE FILLOWING CODE:    NSError *error;
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[manager createSymbolicLinkAtURL:linkPath withDestinationURL:actualFilePath error:&error];

Comment: I've tried to play video directly from server, not local. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: it depend on your requirement ...if you can copy the video file into your directory cache then as per my way you will be able to play the video right away.